# React Custom Hook always behind with one value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Code below is a simplified version of the reality.
It almost works. The issue is in my AddSomething component the value of the snackbar is always one value behind. I've used console logs as you can see in the code.

It goes like this:

1. "inside validateName"
2. "error is set to .... " (inside validateName)
3. "ELSE" (inside addSomething)

So it does everything in correct order. But the error in AddSomething is always one value behind.

So first time I input an empty string and the error message displayed is the default ''
(It should display 'Name can not be below 1')

Second time I try with a string above > 50 characters and it displays the old value of 'Name can not be below 1' but it should be: 'Name can not be above 50'

And it keeps going like this. How can I change the code to actually get the current value?

```
const AddSomething = () => {
 const [error, validate] = useValidation()

 const handleSave = async () => {
    if(await validate(valuesToBeSaved){
      saveItems()
    }else {
      console.log("ELSE")
      setSnackBarError({
        message: error
      })
    }
  }
}

function useValidation() {
 const [error, setError] = useState('')
 let valid = true

 async function validate(valuesToBeSaved: string[] | number[]) {
    for(const value in valuesToBeSaved) {
       if(typeof value === 'string'){
          valid = await validateName(value)
       }
       if(valid === false) return false
    }
 }
  async function validateName(name: string): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log("inside validateName")
    let valid = true
    await nameSchema
      .validate({ name })
      .then((err) => {
        valid = true
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error is set to: " + err.mesage)
        setError(err.message)
        valid = false
      })
    return valid
  }
  return [error, validate]
}

const nameSchema = yup.object({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .min(1, 'Name can not be below 1')
    .max(50, 'Name can not be above 50')
    .required('Name is required'),
})
```

Comment: There are few _problems_ but the visible one is because `validate()` is asynchronous (does it REALLY need to be in the real code?) Inside `handleSave` you call `validate()` and you get `false` then you try to use `error` (which has the PREVIOUS value because they component has not been re-rendered yet after the call to `validate()`).

Comment: I think it needs to be async due to yup library requires that? Or am I wrong?
https://www.techzaion.com/validation-with-yup

Comment: There are few possible fixes: use `useEffect(() => setSnackBarError(error), [error])` (remember to clear `error` inside `useValidation()` when needed). OR. You could return the error from `validate()` (instead of a boolean). OR. Refactor `useValidation()` to _do_ something: it might have a signature like `const [trySubmit, error] = useValidation(saveItems)`. Also note that - unless you're using the super latest TS - then `useValidation()` isn't probably typed as you expect.

Comment: `nameSchema.validate()` is asynchronous but the surrounding code can be greatly simplified

Comment: And...I assume it's again because of the copy & paste but that `for...in...` should really be `for...of...` (if you do not want to change it to `.every(...)`)